# Downloading the uploaded images from google docs in Android app for google docs

Tags: android, google-docs

I have created a small app to upload images to google docs and further i am trying 
download the images i have uploaded. But i am getting Http 500 (Internal Server Error).

Can anybody answer my following queries....

1. Whether google doc api's for android support image download from google docs.
   2.The official android app for google docs does not support downloading of the uploaded images. Is it just a unsupported feature or google docs api for android dont support it yet.

Any help is much appriciated.

Regards
AKS

Comment: Can u please help us with source code for uploading JPEG images to Google docs, using google-client-api for Java?

We have posted our question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739313/uploading-image-to-google-docs-not-working

Thanks in advance.